# parsekit for iOS no compatible with armv7s architecture iPhone 5

Tags: xcode, ios6, armv7

i use the parsekit for iOS for my project, i have install the Xcode 4.5 GM with iOS 6, and in the architecture put automatically armv7s for iPhone 5, but Xcode give me a warning and error:

```
libparsekit.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7s):
```

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

[Go to your project settings (or target settings, if they are overridden at the target level), and edit the Architectures setting from armv7 armv7s to armv7.](http://wanderingcoder.net/2012/09/16/no-armv7s-til-tested/)